# Macro for wrapping tests with re-frame run-test-sync not working

Tags: clojure, macros

I have this following idiom in my code:

```
(deftest my-test
   (run-test-sync
       (is (= 1 2)) ;; etc.
   )
```

And it seems like a good idea to create a macro which would replicate this like so:

```
(deftest-sync my-test
   (is (= 1 2))
)
```

And I have tried this:

```
(defmacro deftest-sync [name test]
  `(deftest ~name ~(run-test-sync ~test))
  )
```

But on doing :

```
(macroexpand '(deftest-sync some-test (is (= 1 1))))
```

I simply get the result:

```
(deftest-sync some-test (is (= 1 1)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

-- EDIT --
My second attempt is this:

```
(defmacro deftest-sync [name & test]
  `(deftest ~name (run-test-sync ~@test))
  )
```

But the macro expansion is still:

```
(deftest-sync some-test (is (= 1 1)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your second version is OK. I tested this on a Clojure (JVM) REPL with CIDER:

```clj
(ns macrodemo.core)

(defmacro deftest-sync [name & test]
  `(deftest ~name (run-test-sync ~@test)))

;; (macroexpand '(deftest-sync some-test (is (= 1 1))))
;; => (macrodemo.core/deftest some-test (macrodemo.core/run-test-sync (is (= 1 1))))
;;
;; ... which is basically:
;; (deftest some-test (run-test-sync (is (= 1 1))))
```